# Control the starting angle at which the point rotates on the circle

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to get the `dot` to start rotating at an angle of `330 degrees`, but it starts at that point, jumps to `0 degrees`, and does a full turn from `0 degrees` to `360 degrees`.

I'm trying to make it start at `330 degree`s and end at `330 degrees`.

[image]

Can anybody help me?

```
from manim import *
import numpy as np

class Turn( Scene ):
    def construct( self ):
        radius = 1

        origin = ORIGIN 
        e1dir = RIGHT
        e2dir = UP

        x1 = origin + radius * e1dir * np.cos(np.deg2rad(330)) + radius * e2dir * np.sin(np.deg2rad(330))
        r = lambda t: origin + radius * e1dir * np.cos(t * 1 * 2*PI) + radius * e2dir * np.sin(t * 1 * 2*PI)

        def rmove(a, t):
            p = r(t)
            a.move_to(p)

        def u1(mob):
            t = t_parameter.get_value()
            rmove(mob, t)

        t_parameter = ValueTracker(0)
        dot = Dot(point=x1, color=BLUE).add_updater(u1)

        g1 = ParametricFunction(r, t_range=[0, 1], color=YELLOW)

        self.add(VGroup(g1, dot))
        self.wait(1)

        self.play(UpdateFromAlphaFunc(t_parameter, lambda mob, alpha: mob.set_value(alpha)), run_time=3)
        self.wait(1)
```

Comment: `r(0)!=x1`: isn’t that the problem?